# Write a program that will take three integers as input and will print the second largest number

Tags: c, if-statement, nested-if

I have tried this program to take 3 integers and print the 2nd largest number:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,max2;
    printf("Enter 3 integers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    max2=a;
    if(a>b){
        max2=b;
        printf("")
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now i am stuck here. I am unable to find the logic behind this code. What can I do?

Comment: Where is the comparison with `c`?

Comment: @EdHeal I am stuck here. That's why I didn't complete it.

Comment: Do not read user input using `scanf()`. (The main purpose of the `scanf()` familiy is to read "known good" input, i.e. ideally something that an earlier run of your program had written itself. It is not so good for recovering from faulty input.) Do not **ever** use `scanf()` on user input without checking the return value... `scanf()` can *fail to match*. The generic advice is to read complete lines of input (using `fgets()` and then parsing that input line in memory (with e.g. `strtol()`).

Comment: @DevSolar I want to get the logic behind this code to print the 2nd largest number.

Comment: And I pointed out some significant shortcoming in that code not directly related to the question, hence a comment, not an answer.

Comment: what are you stuck on? Forget the code for a moment, can you think of an algorithm to find the 2nd largest of any 3 numbers? Do you already have an algorithm in mind but don't know how to translate it to C code?

Comment: @yano Thanks a lot for your approach. But I already got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the **Logic** which you can understand, it'll not give you the right, expected result.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Values: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    if(a>b && a>c)
    {
        if(b>c)
            printf("2nd largest: %d", b);
        else
            printf("2nd largest: %d", c);
    }
    else if(b>c && b>a)
    {
        if(c>a)
            printf("2nd largest: %d", c);
        else
            printf("2nd largest: %d", a);
    }
    else if(a>b)
            printf("2nd largest: %d", a);
        else
            printf("2nd largest: %d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

You should compare all the three variables to get the `2nd largest` among those numbers.

**Output:**

```
Values: 32 31 12
2nd largest: 31
```

**Explanation:**

First pick any variable and compare it with the other two variables like `if(a>b && a>c)`, if its `true`, it means `a` is the `largest` and any of the two variables `b` and `c`  is the `2nd largest`, so inside the `if(a>b && a>c)` block there's a comparison `if(b>c)`, if `true` then `b` is the 2nd largest otherwise `c` is the second largest. Similarly, compare the other two variables for if they are the largest. e.g. `else if(b>c && b>a)` and `else if(c>a && c>b)`.

Comment: I wanted to print the second largest, not the largest number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218175/discussion-between-maria-and-lucas).

Comment: This doesn't work for the values 4 8 3 (more generally, doesn't work for values entered in the order `middle largest smallest`)

Comment: @yano there's just a little mistake in the second block `else if(b>c && b>a)`. I just swapped the comparison values. You're great.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to sort these three numbers and then print the middle one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void swap_if_out_of_order (int *p, int *q)
{
    if (*p > *q) {
        int t = *p;
        *p = *q;
        *q = t;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter three integers\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
        swap_if_out_of_order(&a, &b);
        swap_if_out_of_order(&b, &c);
        swap_if_out_of_order(&a, &b);
        printf("Second greatest: %d\n", b);
    }
}
```

Or, without sorting, with at most three comparisons:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a, b, c, m;
    
    printf("Enter three integers\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
        if (a > b) {
            if      (b > c) m = b;
            else if (a > c) m = c;
            else            m = a;
        } else   if (a > c) m = a;
          else   if (b > c) m = c;
          else              m = b;
        printf("Second greatest: %d\n", m);
    }
}
```

or, likely the most efficient way with max and min functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int min (int x, int y) { return x < y ? x : y; }
static inline int max (int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }

int main (void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    
    printf("Enter three integers\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
        printf("Second greatest: %d\n", max(min(a, b), min(max(a, b), c)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS recursion:

```js
function f(a,b,c) {
  if(a>=b && c<b) return b;
  if(a>b) return f(a,c,b);
   return f(b,a,c);
}

f(2,12,0) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       #include <stdio.h>
        main()
       {
              int a,b,c;

               scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
               // largest //
               if(a>b&&a>c)
               printf("largest=%d",a);
               if(b>a&&b>c)
               printf("largest=%d",b);
               if(c>b&&c>a)
              printf("largest=%d",c);
             // second largest//
              if(a>b&&a<c)
             printf("\nscenond largest=%d",a);
            if(b>a&&b<c)
             printf("\nscenond largest=%d",b);
             if(c>a&&c<b)
           printf("\nscenond largest=%d",c);

       }


this will output the largest and the second largest number.
```

Comment: The question asked was how to return the second largest only, not the largest as well. Refine your response. Additionally, your answer misses some cases, for example if  b > c > a (you only have a > c > b)